# Specify Axios response type on post request with body

Tags: typescript, post, axios, request

I'm trying to specify both the JSON body and the response type (which are different, some samples out there somehow have the same for both).

Error message:

> Argument of type '{ grant_type: string; refresh_token: string; }' is
> not assignable to parameter of type 'AuthResponse'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'grant_type'
> does not exist in type 'AuthResponse'.

Here's the response I defined as my type:

```
export interface AuthResponse {
  token: string;
  token_type: string;

  access_token: string;
  access_token_expires_at: string;

  refresh_token: string;
  refresh_token_expires_at: string;
}
```

Use of axios:

```
axios
      .post<AuthResponse>(
        secrets.authURL,//Defined in enclosing class
        {
          grant_type: this.grantType,//Defined in enclosing class
          refresh_token: this.authPayload,//Defined in enclosing class
        },//<-- Defined as data and conflicts with AuthResponse
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: this.getAuthHeader(),//Defined in enclosing class
            "Content-Type": this.contentType,///Defined in enclosing class
          },
        }
      )
      .then((axiosResp) => {
        const response = axiosResp.data;//<-- Not the type I'd expect
      });
```

`axiosResp.data` is of type `{grant_type: ..., refresh_token: ...}` instead of `AuthResponse`.

From the plain JS samples, data is the body for the request, but not sure why it would be forced as being the same for the response, so I must be doing something very wrong.

**Edit/Answer:**
As pointed by @jrsharpe's comment, this IS a bug, they also just released [v0.23.0](https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v0.23.0) a few hours ago. It fixes the [bug #4116](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/4116). So just upgrade to 0.23.0+.

Comment: I think this is a bug: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4176

Comment: Either the response is wrong or the interface is wrong, the fields in response and typing are total different

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are correct, this seems to be a bug. To confirm I am using axios 0.22.0 as listed in the report. I downgraded to 0.21.4 and it now works. This is the answer. Please post and I can assign it to you.

Answer (score 3):

you can type both like this

```
interface AuthResponse {
    token: string;
    token_type: string;

    access_token: string;
    access_token_expires_at: string;

    refresh_token: string;
    refresh_token_expires_at: string;
}

interface TBody {
    grant_type: string
    refresh_token: string
}

const t = async (): Promise<void> => {

    const data = await axios.post<AuthResponse, AxiosResponse<AuthResponse, TBody>, TBody>("theurl", {
        grant_type: 'kjkjk',
        refresh_token: "dddf",
    }, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "dfdfds",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })

    const resu: AuthResponse = data.data

}
```

Comment: Based on documentation and the recent bug report, this does not seem to be the intended way to use the library. Thanks for the contribution however!

Comment: I'm using axios like this for ages, and there is no bug at all. The code above  is based on "axios": "^0.23.0". just try it and check that this is fine